# Using Mongo compound indexes

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to create a compound index for a popular query.

There are two fields.  A 'client' field of type String, containing an IP address.  The other is a 'sendOn' field which is of type Date.  I'm looking for documents where the client is null and the sendOn is between a certain range.

To support ascending sorting on the sendOn field, I've established that I need a sendOn index with a value of 1.

So, I've run

```
> db.queries.ensureIndex({"client":1,"sendOn":1})

> db.queries.find({ $query:  { client: { $exists: false }  , sendOn: { $gt: new Date(1387664033883), $lt: new Date(1387750493883) } } }).explain()

{
        "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
        "nscanned" : 2546133,
        "nscannedObjects" : 2546133,
        "n" : 0,
        "millis" : 25071,
        "nYields" : 0,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "isMultiKey" : false,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "indexBounds" : {

        }
}
```

The documentation says that $exists queries are generally inefficient.  I've considered forcing documents to contain at least an empty client field.  But that query doesn't use the index either?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should use the index (provided you replace the $exists by a null value, as you mentioned - the $exists operator is not optimized for indexes).

You may be messing things up here at some point : documentation states you shouldn't use .explain() with a $query format :

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/meta/query/

Try this :

```
db.queries.find({ $query:  { client: null  , sendOn: { $gt: new Date(1387664033883), $lt: new Date(1387750493883) } }, $explain: true });
```

Comment: Thanks for the null shortcut.  It's nice to have something familiar.